# Traveling to Ireland

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, ireland, thai-citizens

I have some plan to travel to Ireland. I have currently working in Netherland. I am non-eu citizen but have Netherland identity card and was wondering if I need to apply for visa to visit Ireland for a few days.

Comment: @user76954 What’s your citizenship?

Comment: I have thai passport

Comment: YES, you need a visa.

Comment: @user76954 You can check visa requirements for Ireland based on nationality here http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa